# Procurve VLAN configuration

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve

I have two ProCurve 1800-24G J9028B linked toghether by a fiber channel on ports n.23. I want an ethernet port (ex. port 21 of switch n1) to be isolated from all the others except of one of the other switch (ex. port 21 of switch n2).
How to setup this VLAN by web interface? May i just add ports 21 to VLAN2 or I have also to add the 23 (fiber link) port?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ports neem to be member of the same VLAN group, the fiber port needs to be member as well.

So:

```
Switch 1 port 21 - Groupmember of VLAN2
Switch 2 Port 21 - Groupmember of VLAN2
Switch 1 Port 23 (FC Trunck) - groupmember of VLAN2
Switch 2 Port 23 (FC Trunck) - groupmember of VLAN2
```

you will need to set the 21 ports to be tagged with VLAN2 ID, otherwise not a lot will happen

Comment: Both port 23 must also be member of VLAN1... am I right?
Trunks and LACP have nothing to do with this VLAN?

Comment: Both 23's need to be member of any VLAN you wish to route through them. 

So, if VLAN1 is your "normal" LAN and VLAN2 for instance is a VLAN for the "guest wireless" then port 23 needs to be member of both VLAN Group 1 and 2, Correct.

Comment: I have a little question about VLAN. Do you think VLAN is a good solution for heavy file transfer throught LAN? I build up that VLAN to connect server storage to backup NAS, someone said that VLAN reduces traffic in the main LAN during backup transfers. Do you agree?

Comment: Look at it this way,

if you have a 1 Gigabit link with 20VLAN's or 2VLAN's, you still only have 1Gb Link. VLAN's aren't used to to enhance the throughput of a network, but to segregate network traffic from causing collisions or impacting one another.

So in terms of speed it does nothing for you, a 1Gb link is a 1Gb link, and everything the VLAN consumes won't be available for the "normal" LAN to consume.

Don't worry about it too much though, only the link to the server being backed up is affected. The switch itself won't be impacted.

Try "Link Aggregation" for that

Comment: and (ran out of comment space) Yes it is good. 

Why ? 
The load on the network the data packets for the file transfer will be segregated from the rest of the LAN, not being able to impact the performance of for instance the RDP connection to the server (just using it as an example) or another service running on it.

It's like in some companies when using iSCSI over a existing LAN infrastructure iSCSI traffic gets put in its own VLAN, to prevent it from impacting the rest of the network under heavy load.

Again though, a 1Gb link is a 1Gb link. VLAN doesn't magically enhance the speed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So dividing the main LAN can be useful for services performance (es. voip, rdp, iscsi) not for global throughput.